# Operation to create a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trailblazer

I want to create an operation which accepts a json array and creates several objects. Something like `Books::CreateCollection`. 
I believe I need to somehow reuse `Books::Create` - just call it multiple times and wrap the whole loop in transaction.

json:

```
{
 "books": [
    {
       title: "A Tale Of Two Cities"
    },
    {
       title: "Don Quixote"
    }
 ]
}
```

But how the contract of `Books::CreateCollection` should look like?

Trailblazer `0.3.0`

Answer (score 2):

Your contract can handle this.

```
contract do
  model Book # since you don't call this on the operation.

  collection :songs, populate_if_empty: Book do
    property :title
  end
end
```

This is basic Reform wizardry.

The contract will now create one `Book` instance per incoming hash fragment in the `songs` array.

Comment: Is this still valid on the latest version? Can't seem to be able to find a way to get it working.